# Need Help in regex for detecting google conversion ID

Tags: php, regex

I have a script that crawls for coversion and remarketing code, but I need help in detecting the conversion ID, 
Ex:

```
<!-- Google Code for current client Remarketing List -->
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
var google_conversion_id = 1057577648; 
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "666666";
var google_conversion_label = "FJ8sCKCE9wEQsLWl-AM";
var google_conversion_value = 0;
/* ]]> */
```

Need a regex for something like this:

```
$gaRegExp = "Regex Here";

preg_match( $gaRegExp , $str , $matches);

$conversion_id = $matches;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$subject = 'var google_conversion_id = 1057577648; 
var google_conversion_language = "en";
var google_conversion_format = "3";
var google_conversion_color = "666666";
var google_conversion_label = "FJ8sCKCE9wEQsLWl-AM";
var google_conversion_value = 0;';
$pattern = '!(?<=google_conversion_id\s\=\s)\d+!';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 1057577648 )
```

To get the element `$conversion_id=$matches[0];`